chip 8 emulator defining variables
hi guy's i'm trying to implement a chip8 emulator using c via reading this guide https://tobiasvl.github.io/blog/write-a-chip-8-emulator/#fetch i'm trying to define the base variables for the chip8 emulator but in some places i have no idea what i am doing. so basically i wanted to do is this part where defining variables
so here is my code for that. i would like to know if i am doing something wrong and if it is i would like to know your advises.
here is the setup

and here is the my code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define NUM_REGISTERS 16

#define V0 registers[0]
#define V1 registers[1]
#define V2 registers[2]
#define V3 registers[3]
#define V4 registers[4]
#define V5 registers[5]
#define V6 registers[6]
#define V7 registers[7]
#define V8 registers[8]
#define V9 registers[9]
#define VA registers[10]
#define VB registers[11]
#define VC registers[12]
#define VD registers[13]  
#define VE registers[14]
#define VF registers[15]

int main(){

    char ram[4096];
    bool display[64*32];
    char *pc;
    uint16_t *indexRegister;
    uint16_t stack[16]; 
    uint8_t delay_timer = 60;
    uint8_t sound_timer = 0;
    
    uint8_t registers[NUM_REGISTERS] = {0};


    return 0;
}


This code is not doing anything. Neither right nor wrong.

I think the "stack" is supposed to be for N 16-bit addresses (not for 16 addresses)

display could be a 2-D array as in the hardware description.

If you make your 'registers' and 'files' larger than they actually are on the PIC, you can more easily set the result flags. For example, where will you get the carry from?
